# How to fix '[LoginVC viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

Im trying to use split view controllers for iphone but when i add the code for AppDelegate.m as below, i get the error. My app also utilises a login system using file LoginVC and that file was working fine before.

[Storyboard image here][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRosR.png

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RightVC.h"
#import "LeftVC.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController 
*)self.window.rootViewController;


UINavigationController *leftNavController = 
[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


LeftVC *leftViewController = (LeftVC *)[leftNavController 
topViewController];


RightVC *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers 
objectAtIndex:1];


Recipe *firstRecipe = [[leftViewController recipes] objectAtIndex:0];

[rightViewController setRecipe:firstRecipe];

return YES;
}
```

And my LoginVC.m

```
#import "LoginVC.h"

@interface LoginVC ()

@end

@implementation LoginVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.checkLogin = [[LoginService alloc]init];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *) title: (int) tag {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, 
nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little 
preparation before navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {
    if([self.txtUsername.text isEqualToString:@""] || [self.txtPassword.text 
isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Username and/or Password cannot be blank!" 
:@"Sign in Failed" :0];
    } else{
        self.checkLogin.strUsername = self.txtUsername.text;
        self.checkLogin.strPassword = self.txtPassword.text;

        BOOL lgs = self.checkLogin.success;

        if(lgs==1){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMain" sender:self];

        }else{
            [self alertStatus:@"Wrong Username and/or Password!" :@"Sign in 
Failed":0];
        }
    }

}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
    [self.txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [[self.view window] endEditing:YES];
}

@end
```

Been trying to fix but all i have are a few split view guides on the net

Comment: Show your storyboard?

Comment: Added as link .

Comment: Don't add it as link. This can break.

Comment: How you showing LoginVC?

Comment: Edited in! Sorry i cant embed images cus im still new on stackoverflow

Comment: @Kerry Chin search  the string "viewControllers" entire project, is there any function call like that? also make sure any outlet with same name in storyboard that are not included in the corresponding class

Comment: I searched up the project and there are no other functions except in AppDelegate.m. I did some debugging and found out "UINavigationController *leftNavController = 
[splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];" was the problem. However i cant seem to find a solution for it